# Image slider app in Reactjs using two child components

Tags: reactjs

I have two child components and I'm calling them from App.js.There is an issue in displaying the selected image. The currentIndex value is not getting set properly in the child components.
All I want is to display the image in the viewer.js and prev and next should as expected.

App.js - The App.js file contains the main functionalities for the slider.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import previousIcon from './assets/icons/left-icon.png';
import nextIcon from './assets/icons/right_icon.png';
import thumb1 from './assets/images/thumb/tea-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb2 from './assets/images/thumb/white-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb3 from './assets/images/thumb/pink-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb4 from './assets/images/thumb/tea-light-thumb.jpeg';
import image1 from './assets/images/tea-light.jpeg';
import image2 from './assets/images/white-light.jpeg';
import image3 from './assets/images/pink-light.jpeg';
import image4 from './assets/images/tea-light.jpeg';

import './App.css';
import Viewer from "./components/Viewer";
import Thumbs from "./components/Thumbs";


const catalogs = [
  {
    thumb: thumb1,
    image: image1
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb2,
    image: image2
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb3,
    image: image3
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb4,
    image: image4
  }
];

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'Catalog Viewer',
      catalogs: [...catalogs],
      currentIndex: 0,
      catalogSelected: catalogs[3],
      slideActive: false,
      slideTimer: null,
      slideDuration: 3000,
    };
    this.selectedCatalog = this.selectedCatalog.bind(this);
    this.previousClick = this.previousClick.bind(this);
    this.nextClick = this.nextClick.bind(this);
    this.slideChange = this.slideChange.bind(this);
    this.resetSlideTimer = this.resetSlideTimer.bind(this);
    this.onSlideChange = this.onSlideChange.bind(this);
  }

  selectedCatalog(index) {
    console.log("index : ", index)
    // console.log("catalogs[index] : ",catalogs[index])
    // this.state.currentIndex = index
    if (catalogs[index] === this.state.currentIndex) {
      this.setState({
        catalogSelected : catalogs[index],
        currentIndex : index
      })
    }
  }

  previousClick() {
    console.log("prev before : ", this.state.currentIndex)
    if (this.state.currentIndex ? this.state.currentIndex  === -1 : this.state.currentIndex  === 0 ) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.catalogs.length - 1 
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex - 1
      })
    }
    console.log("prev after : ", this.state.currentIndex)
  }

  nextClick() {
    console.log("next before: ", this.state.currentIndex)
    if (this.state.currentIndex === this.state.catalogs.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1
      })
    }
    console.log("next after : ", this.state.currentIndex)
  }

  slideChange(event) {
    
  }

  resetSlideTimer(isActive = false) {

  }

  onSlideChange() {

  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="title" data-testid="app-title"> {this.state.title} </div>
          <div className="catalog-outer">
            <div className="catalog-view">
              <div className="text-center">
                <div className="view-outter text-center">
                  <Viewer catalog={this.state.catalogSelected.image}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="catalog-items">
              <div className="previous" onClick={this.previousClick} data-testid="prev-icon">
                <img src={previousIcon}/>
              </div>
              <div className="next" onClick={this.nextClick} data-testid="next-icon">
                <img src={nextIcon}/>
              </div>
              <Thumbs items={this.state.catalogs} currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex} selectedCatalog={this.selectedCatalog(this.state.currentIndex)}/>
            </div>

            <div className="slide-input">
              <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.slideChange} className="test" data-testid="slide"/> Slide
            </div>
          </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thumbs.js - This contains the thumbnail view of the image.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './Thumbs.css';

class Thumbs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.onImageSelect = this.onImageSelect.bind(this);
    }

    onImageSelect(event) { 
        this.props.currentIndex = event.target.id
        event.preventDefault();
        var index = event.target.currentIndex
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {
                this.props.items.map((catalog,idx) => (
                    <span className="catalog item"  onClick={(idx) => this.onImageSelect(idx)} className={'thumb-select'} id={idx} key={idx} data-testid={'thumb_outer_'+idx}>
                        <span className={"thumb-outer " + (idx == this.props.currentIndex ? 'thumb-selected' : '')} data-testid={'thumb_'+idx}>
                            <span className="thumb" id={idx} style={{ backgroundImage: 'url('+ catalog.thumb + ')'}} data-testid={'thumb_img_'+idx} />
                        </span>
                    </span>
                ))
            }

        </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Thumbs;
```

Viewer.js - This contains the enlarged view of the image.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './Viewer.css';

class Viewer extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div className="catalog-view">
        <img data-testid="catalog-view" className="catalog-image" src={this.props.catalog}/>
      </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default Viewer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in the Thumbs component. Take a look at the `onClick` prop on the `span.catalog.item`.

Notice that you have defined an inline function that takes the argument `(idx)`?

`onClick={(idx) => this.onImageSelect(idx)}`

When you click on that element, the argument passed to that click handler is actually the browser event, not the current index.

Instead, write your `onClick` prop like this:

`onClick={() => this.onImageSelect(idx)}`

That way `idx`, is actually the index provided in your map function.

## Edit: Okay, I see that there are additional issues here, so let me give you a more complete answer.

In your `App` component you have the state variable: `currentIndex`, you pass this down to the `Thumbs` component. All good.

You want to update the `currentIndex` in the `App` component when a user clicks on a thumbnail.

However, in your `onImageSelect` function, you are mistakenly attempting to modify the props that were given to it. This is wrong.

### As a rule, a component must never mutate or modify the props.

Instead, `App` should provide a function to change the `currentIndex` to the `Thumbs` component.

Like this:

In the `App` component add a new method.

```js
  handleThumbClick(index) {
    this.setState({ currentIndex: index });
  }
```

Then pass it as a prop to Thumbs.

```js
            <Thumbs
              items={this.state.catalogs}
              currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex}
              selectedCatalog={this.selectedCatalog(this.state.currentIndex)}
              onThumbClick={this.handleThumbClick}
            />
```

Now inside the `Thumbs` component, we can call that function inside the `onImageSelect` method.

```js
  onImageSelect(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onThumbClick(index);
  }
```

And when we map over the Thumbnails, we define a click handler like this:

```js
          <span
            className="catalog item"
            onClick={(e) => this.onImageSelect(e, index)}
            className={'thumb-select'}
            id={index}
            key={index}
            data-testid={'thumb_outer_' + index}
          >
```

Putting it all together now.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import previousIcon from './assets/icons/left-icon.png';
import nextIcon from './assets/icons/right_icon.png';
import thumb1 from './assets/images/thumb/tea-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb2 from './assets/images/thumb/white-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb3 from './assets/images/thumb/pink-light-thumb.jpeg';
import thumb4 from './assets/images/thumb/tea-light-thumb.jpeg';
import image1 from './assets/images/tea-light.jpeg';
import image2 from './assets/images/white-light.jpeg';
import image3 from './assets/images/pink-light.jpeg';
import image4 from './assets/images/tea-light.jpeg';

import './App.css';
import Viewer from './components/Viewer';
import Thumbs from './components/Thumbs';

const catalogs = [
  {
    thumb: thumb1,
    image: image1,
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb2,
    image: image2,
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb3,
    image: image3,
  },
  {
    thumb: thumb4,
    image: image4,
  },
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'Catalog Viewer',
      catalogs: [...catalogs],
      currentIndex: 0,
      catalogSelected: catalogs[3],
      slideActive: false,
      slideTimer: null,
      slideDuration: 3000,
    };

    this.selectedCatalog = this.selectedCatalog.bind(this);
    this.previousClick = this.previousClick.bind(this);
    this.nextClick = this.nextClick.bind(this);
    this.slideChange = this.slideChange.bind(this);
    this.resetSlideTimer = this.resetSlideTimer.bind(this);
    this.onSlideChange = this.onSlideChange.bind(this);
    this.handleThumbClick = this.handleThumbClick.bind(this);
  }

  selectedCatalog(index) {
    console.log('index : ', index);
    // console.log("catalogs[index] : ",catalogs[index])
    // this.state.currentIndex = index
    if (catalogs[index] === this.state.currentIndex) {
      this.setState({
        catalogSelected: catalogs[index],
        currentIndex: index,
      });
    }
  }

  previousClick() {
    console.log('prev before : ', this.state.currentIndex);
    if (this.state.currentIndex ? this.state.currentIndex === -1 : this.state.currentIndex === 0) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.catalogs.length - 1,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex - 1,
      });
    }
    console.log('prev after : ', this.state.currentIndex);
  }

  nextClick() {
    console.log('next before: ', this.state.currentIndex);
    if (this.state.currentIndex === this.state.catalogs.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: 0,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1,
      });
    }
    console.log('next after : ', this.state.currentIndex);
  }

  slideChange(event) {}

  resetSlideTimer(isActive = false) {}

  onSlideChange() {}

  handleThumbClick(index) {
    this.setState({ currentIndex: index });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="title" data-testid="app-title">
          {' '}
          {this.state.title}{' '}
        </div>
        <div className="catalog-outer">
          <div className="catalog-view">
            <div className="text-center">
              <div className="view-outter text-center">
                <Viewer catalog={this.state.catalogSelected.image} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="catalog-items">
            <div className="previous" onClick={this.previousClick} data-testid="prev-icon">
              <img src={previousIcon} />
            </div>
            <div className="next" onClick={this.nextClick} data-testid="next-icon">
              <img src={nextIcon} />
            </div>
            <Thumbs
              items={this.state.catalogs}
              currentIndex={this.state.currentIndex}
              selectedCatalog={this.selectedCatalog(this.state.currentIndex)}
              onThumbClick={this.handleThumbClick}
            />
          </div>

          <div className="slide-input">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={this.slideChange}
              className="test"
              data-testid="slide"
            />{' '}
            Slide
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import './Thumbs.css';

class Thumbs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.onImageSelect = this.onImageSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onImageSelect(e, index) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onThumbClick(index);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.items.map((catalog, index) => (
          <span
            className="catalog item"
            onClick={(e) => this.onImageSelect(e, index)}
            className={'thumb-select'}
            id={index}
            key={index}
            data-testid={'thumb_outer_' + index}
          >
            <span
              className={
                'thumb-outer ' + (index == this.props.currentIndex ? 'thumb-selected' : '')
              }
              data-testid={'thumb_' + index}
            >
              <span
                className="thumb"
                id={index}
                style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + catalog.thumb + ')' }}
                data-testid={'thumb_img_' + index}
              />
            </span>
          </span>
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I try to click on the thumbs image, i holds to the next or prev button's currentIndex. It doesn't gets updated according to the image i click. Not sure what selectedCatalog in App.js should hold and what changes i need to do in Thumbs.js file under onImageSelect function.

Comment: @Aishwarya I have updated my answer to provide a more complete answer to your question. Take a look and let me know if you have any more questions for me!

Comment: Once again a million thanks for the response! But i wanted to say what I tried before adding the comment. I did set the value of currentIndex : index within my selectedCatalog() function. I had Maximum update depth exceeded error. Then there is no use of  selectedCatalog() function? Because that the one which displays the image in Viewer.js file and its sent as a props within it.

Comment: Also when i try to add the below lines in the selectedCatalog(index) function, I get the Maximum update depth exceeded error. All i'm trying to do is, pass on the index on which i'm clicking to the calalogs array. That way that image gets displayed.

this.setState({
      catalogSelected: catalogs[index]
})